# Identify IC: T7V

Tags: identification

What could that be? I think it is an N-channel FET.

I managed to measure the body diode between pins 1-3 (cathode) and 5-8 (anode).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Diodes Inc. DMT6017LFV](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMT6017LFV.pdf) N-Channel MOSFET (as you suspected).

[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Cheers!